# Can't seem to get this for loop to work with range

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, range

```
numbers = [5, 9, 13, 17, 21] 

for list in range(5,22,4): 
    print(numbers[list], end =" ")
```

Can't seem to get it to work, keep getting

> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Your bad, you have a list with five items, but your loop Stars list with valué 5 them when you indexing numbers[list] you are out o range; your range returns 5,9,13, 17, 21and all valúes are out o range

Answer (score 1):

Your numbers variable has an index from 0-4 (python starts at 0 and increments from there) - your range command is giving you the numbers:

`[5, 9, 13, 17, 21]`

You're telling python that you want to go from the number 5 to the number 22, in steps of 4.  This means that when you try and print numbers[list], the variable `list` is actually the index 5 on the iteration of the for loop, and will be outside of the index range of the numbers variable, since it only has indices 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4

Comment: Two things to note:

1. Try to avoid using reserved names as variables - for list in thing overrides the list, which is used for changing things to lists.
2. If you want to iterate over a list, you can do  ```range(len(thing))```, so for instance you could use:
```for index in range(len(numbers)): print(numbers[index], end=" ")``` - That says for range to take the length of the list and make a range out of it.
3.  Another alternative way would be to just do: ```for number in numbers: print(number, end=" ")```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to confuse two approaches to solving the same task.

One is printing the existing list of numbers:

```
numbers = [5, 9, 13, 17, 21] 

for number in numbers: 
    print(number, end=" ")

# or, alternatively

for index in range(len(numbers)): 
    print(numbers[index], end=" ")
```

Another is generating the same sequence of numbers using `range()` function:

```
for number in range(5,22,4):
    print(number, end=" ")

# or, reusing one of the previous approaches

numbers = range(5,22,4)

for number in numbers: 
    print(number, end=" ")
```

Bear in mind that `range()` creates a range object, which is suitable for enumeration and indexing, but does not support other list operations like slicing, concatenation and repeating (concatenation with itself). If you want to get `numbers` as a list, write explicitly:

```
numbers = list(range(5,22,4))
```

and then you can do:

```
for number in numbers * 2: 
    print(number, end=" ")
```

which will print your sequence of numbers twice.

Comment: Please add an explanation